# AmCharts 4 DataSource: Force chart to wait for all external data to load

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using AmCharts 4 to create a scatter plot with external data, using this code to point to the external URL:

```
dataURL = 'http://somesite.com/page?params=1234';
ScatterChart.dataSource.disableCache = true;
ScatterChart.dataSource.url = dataURL;
```

The chart loads; however, each time I load the chart, it is giving me a different set of data, and it always is missing significant chunks of the data I am expecting. When I go to `dataURL` the external data downloads onto into its URL over a period of approximately 20 seconds.  I think it is not waiting for the data source page to finish downloading information before graphing.

**Is there a way to force AmCharts to wait for a data source to finish loading before graphing a chart?**

Here is a screenshot of the network view of `dataURL`:

[image: screenshot of the network view]

Comment: Just a fyi, this has caught our attention and we'll let you know when we've had a chance to look it over.

Comment: amCharts 4 does not have any timeouts for data load built in. It also does not initiate build of the chart with only-partially loaded data. I'm suspecting that something might be happening with the actual data source, like maybe there are some server-side execution limits that are hit that cause only partial data to be generated. I suggest you try accessing the data URL directly and checking whether it loads fully, there are no errors - both in output and in response headers.

Comment: @martynasma Content appears on the page after "Waiting (TTFB)" period of 1.26 seconds on the screenshot above; however, it loads continuously into the page during the 21.39 seconds of "Content Download". Visually, you can watch the scrollbar get smaller, and if you scroll to the bottom it will keep loading in content underneath. At first, I tried loading the data myself via Ajax and sending it to the chart's data object, but it ended up crashing my browser with very high memory usage (data is only 13Mb). I ended up switching the chart back to an AmCharts3 dataLoader and it worked quickly.

Comment: Let me know if there is any kind of diagnostic information that might be useful. I manage the dataURL as well.

Comment: Also, there are no errors in the response or the actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepped away from this project for a while, but started again recently and determined that the reason the chart was only showing certain data points was due to the sort order of the data, not any sort of timeout on data loading.

In this case, I will describe what happened when I was building a scatter XY chart with a date X axis and a value Y axis.

[The documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/) says that order can be important for a Line Series due to the confusing way in which the lines will be connected, but it doesn't say that out of order data wouldn't be shown. When I was experimenting, I saw that this is not necessarily the case.

**When I sorted by date X axis ascending, all the data shows.**

`data = data.sort((a, b) => a['DateX'] < b['DateX'] ? -1 : a['DateX'] < b['DateX'] ? 1 : 0)`

[image: Ascending Sort]

**When I did not sort my data by date, it would show only some of my information.**

[image: No Sort]

**When I sorted by my date column descending it only showed one data point on my chart.**

`data = data.sort((a, b) => a['DateX'] > b['DateX'] ? -1 : a['DateX'] > b['DateX'] ? 1 : 0)`
[image: Descending Sort]

So in the end, if this happens to you, make sure to sort your data prior to sending it to the chart.